# Rosserial mbed comunication does not work

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. I downloaded rosserial jade-devel since there is no branch for Kinetic. I have read that some people used it and it worked. When I am trying to connect to my STM using

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=115200
```

there is an allert:

```
[ERROR] [1518733110.399872]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I am using mbed online compiler, I tried to change baud rate and library on compiler to both kinetic and jade mbed.

My USB-UART device is connected to ttyUSB0. Is there an official Kinetic rosserial version? Do You have any idea what should I do to fix it and make it run? Thank You for answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282890/rosserial-mbed-comunication-does-not-work/) by [Kilmulis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33720/kilmulis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosserial_python` was a bit unstable when I used it to connect an Arduino to ROS.
Could you try using `rosserial_server` instead? That worked properly for me.

> $ roslaunch rosserial_server
> serial.launch

You can see my question here, it might work as an example for you.
https://answers.ros.org/question/233560/rosserial_python-fails-but-rosserial_server-doesnt/

---

Originally posted by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) with karma: 101 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0